# What's wrong with my JDBC select prepared statement?

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm trying to debug my prepared statement in java and I'm stuck on this `checkEmail` function that I implemented. When I go into debugging and it reaches the `setString` line, it shows NOT SPECIFIED in place of the `'?'`. If I hardcode `'findEmail'` into the String query it will work and find the email. Here is the piece of code:

```
public static boolean checkEmail(String findEmail) {
    Connection conn = EstablishConnection.conn;
    boolean found = false;
    try {
        String query = "SELECT email FROM customers WHERE email=?";
        Logging.debug(query);
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1,findEmail);
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);
        //Iterate through the results of the query
        if (rs.next()) {
            found = true;
        }
        preparedStatement.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Logging.debug("Exception thrown in CustomerOperations.getCustomerInfo(): " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return found;

}
```

Comment: you need `ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();`

Comment: Darn I figured it was something simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace this :

```
  ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(query);
```

With:

```
  ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Because you had already pass the query to `prepareStatement` : `conn.prepareStatement(query);`

Comment: Thanks that did it! Probably did it before without prepared and switched over and forgot to remove.